# Something wrong with enum

Tags: c++

I've something like:

```
enum Direction{Forward,Backward};

template<Direction dir = Forward>
class X
{
private:

    Direction my_direction_;
public:

    void set_direction(Direction dir)//here I'm getting an error
    {
        my_direction_ = dir;
    }

};
```

*error: declaration of 'Direction dir'*
Any reason why? BTW, it does compile with VS2010.

Comment: Something like this usually does not work with a compiler. Why not copy and paste the exact code. Speculating an answer to a question that may or may not be the real question is pointless. Also Cut and paste the error message and tell us which compiler you are using and the name of the file the code is in.

Comment: PS. Its probably because you function parameter name is the same as you template parameter name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
template<Direction dir = Forward>
```

to

```
template<Direction direction = Forward>
```

The **[error on gcc](http://ideone.com/voGZl)** is more descriptive:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘void X<dir>::set_direction(Direction)’:
prog.cpp:11: error: declaration of ‘Direction dir’
prog.cpp:3: error:  shadows template parm ‘Direction dir’
```

Comment: #Als, thanks, indeed it works. Interesting thing is that I do compile with gcc and the only error line I've got is the one I've pasted. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @smallB: what's the version of gcc you use ? They worked on improving error messages of late.

Comment: @smallB: *Ideone* uses **gcc-4.3.4**, perhaps you have a different version of gcc, I am not sure why It won't show you the same error Especially, since the error can be seen without any special warning flags on Ideone.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this:

```
 void set_direction(Direction _dir = dir)
 {
      my_direction_ = _dir;
 }
```

The method parameter should not have the same name as the template parameter name.

Comment: Leading underscore is not a good idea.  Identifiers with a leading underscore are reserved for the implementation, in C as well as C++.  C++ also reserves those that contain a double underscore anywhere.

Comment: @cvoinescu I agree. It was just a quick response.

Answer (score 2):

Because you defined dir before in template line

change its name to _dir in constructor